# Comparing EXTRACT(YEAR FROM table.date) to variable value in IntelliJ IDE

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc, intellij-idea, prepared-statement

I'm trying to get flight `count(rate)` per month for **particular variable year** from my database using following query:

```
SELECT EXTRACT(MONTH FROM departure_date) AS month, COUNT(*) AS flight_rate 
FROM flight
WHERE EXTRACT(YEAR FROM departure_date) = ?
GROUP BY EXTRACT(MONTH FROM departure_date);
```

Then, I have following Java code:

```
prepStatement = connection.prepareStatement(query);
prepStatement.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(yearTxtField.getText()));
```

The number 1 in `prepStatement.setInt(...)` keeps being underlined with an  error saying:

> Cannot resolve query parameter 1

So, my query is obviously wrong.

My question is, how to compare the extracted year in where clause with variable year input from text field, using prepared statement?

**EDIT:** So, after I've tried to run the code anyway, ignoring IDE underline error, everything works fine and I will get the wanted result. However when I'm trying to run this query alone in intelliJ with right click and execute, I will get an error:

> [2016-04-09 02:34:09] [42601] ERROR: syntax error at or near "GROUP"
>   Position: 135

Comment: Wait, that error message is only a statement from your IDE then?
What happens when you try to compile/run the code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to ignore "cannot resolve query parameter" error in IntelliJ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740639/how-to-ignore-cannot-resolve-query-parameter-error-in-intellij)

Comment: Okay, so now I've tried to print out result set and obviously it will get filled properly with all data but why is there this underline error in IDE then? And why, when im trying to run query alone, I will get an error: ...syntax error at or near "GROUP"...

Comment: That's a very different question :) Explanation for the IDE is provided by @Titus. About "GROUP", you can replace that query part by "GROUP BY 1", PostgreSQL will refer to the 1st selected column, it might avoid issues. There is no reason it should fail if you replaced the "?" character with a double value. So it must be related to your IDE's behavior of that "right-click > Execute" function, what should happen when the "?" character? If it's not replaced, it's normal it fails.

Comment: Normally when right-click > Execute, new window should open asking me for specifying the parameter represented by "?" in my query. Instead I will get this error. Anyway, my major problem has been solved (or never really existed :D ) so as you say, this is another question.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if related to that error message, but PostgreSQL's `extract` function returns a `double precision` (more [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-TABLE)).

So you might want to try `setDouble(int parameterIndex, double x)` instead of `setInt(int parameterIndex, int x)`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer, but I've tried this and it is not related to my error message.